# Getting all fields in Elastic 1.7

Tags: elasticsearch

According to the [documentation of ElasticSearch 1.7](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-request-fields.html#search-request-fields):

```
Fields: Allows to selectively load specific stored fields for 
        each document represented by a search hit.

{
    "fields" : ["user", "postDate"],
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}

* can be used to load all stored fields from the document.
```

Hence, I tried the following to retrieve all fields:

```
{
    "fields" : ["*"],
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

Without success, so far.

Comment: If you want to retrieve all the fields, you don't need to specify anything. You get all fields in the `_source` field.

Answer (score 0):

just remove fields

```
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

Comment: this returns the full set, but nested deeper under `_source`; I would like the result format to be the same as when I select a subset of fields, i.e. to get the fields under `fields`. This seems to be possible according to the documentation, but so far I haven't figured out how.

Comment: Then you can just add the parameter _search?filter_path=hits.hits._source